# How do I migrate varbinary data to Netezza?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, netezza, varbinary

I got a warning message while migrating DDL from SQL Server to Netezza:

> Warning: [dbo].[spec_binarymessage].[blobdata] data type [varbinary] is not supported the target system and will be scripted as VARCHAR(16000).

I'm wondering whether this kind of data conversion will cause some issues such as truncation of data etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Best is to test it as **Netezza does not support varbinary**. So it has to be converted to a supported varchar(16000) or VARCHAR(64000), VARCHAR(n), NVARCHAR(16000), NVARCHAR(n).

Test your migration plan before hand.

Answer (score 0):

If Netezza supports some other data type which can be as long as your longest value, then you'll be find.  Just create that new column with the needed length and do a test migration of the data in that table.  If it doesn't, then you'll need to change your migration plans to a platform that supports your data.